# How to load an image from the library to the loader component using AS2?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5, loader

I need to load (dynamically) an image stored in the library of Adobe Flash to the loader component. So far, i have imported this image to the library and exported it to ActionScript under the linkage section. I have named its identifier as well.

I am using ActionScript 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as long as your image is in the library, there's no need to use a Loader component. You should use it to load external ressources, not already existing one.

In your case, instead of using a loader, you can simply do

`var myLoadedImage = myContainer.attachMovie( "imageLinkageId", "customImageInstanceName", myContainer.getNextHighestDepth());`

Comment: Thanks for your note. Please in your answer above, what does "myContainer" stands for?

Comment: I assumed you needed some kind of container (because you wanted to use an image loader), so it's just a movieclip that'll hold your newly instancied image.

You can just put it this way : <code> var myLoadedImage = attachMovie( "imageLinkageId", "customImageInstanceName", getNextHighestDepth());</code>